# Multiple instances of StreamWriter working on multiple different disk files in multiple different tasks. Could I run into threading problems?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, streamwriter

I have a C# application that creates multiple tasks (class System.Threading.Tasks.Task).
Each of these tasks writes to a file, each one writes to a different file from the others, using a different StreamWriter instance.

Microsoft's docs says that:
"By default, a StreamWriter is not thread safe."

This means that I could run into problems also in the case described above?

Comment: If each of the thread function writes to a different file using their own copy of the StreamWriter, then yo do not have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

**"StreamWriter is not thread safe."** only means that
it is not safe to use multiple threads on the SAME StreamWriter instance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are saying each `task` is writing to a *different file* with its own **dedicated** instance of `StreamWriter`, you do **not** have a problem. You need not do  synchronization in your scenario.
Only if a single streamwriter instance is used by multiple thread functions then there is a need to do `lock` based *synchronization*.